# How do I solve this exact differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives

> The DE is $\;xy^4 dx + y^2 e^{-x} dy=0$.

If I set $M(x,y) = xy^4$ and $N(x,y)=y^2e^{-x}$ then the

$\int M(x,y) \; dx = \dfrac{(y^4x^2)}{2}$

and

$\int N(x,y) \; dy = \dfrac{(e^{-x}y^3)}{3}$.

At this point I am completely stuck and I have no idea how to continue. I do understand that for some equations that $N(x,y)$ is the derivative of $F(x,y)$ in terms of y but how does that work for this equation? How do I find $F(x,y)$?

Comment: Have you tried [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables)?

Comment: Not all differentials are exact. That method doesn't work for all DEs.

Comment: It does work for all first order differential equations. But you must multiply by the integrating factor. Check out ``integrating factor'' and you shall find the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

As mlainz commented, the equation is separable and write $$x e^x dx =-\frac {dy}{y^2}$$ what you can easily integrate (the lhs will need integration by parts; the rhs is obvious).

Please, since we divided both sides by $y^4$, we assumed that $y \neq 0$. $y=0$ is also a solution of the equation.